# How to access instance variables in Groovy?

Tags: debugging, groovy, intellij-idea, gradle, scope

I have the following class:

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    private String param;

    void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    @TaskAction
    void action() {
        if (param == "test") {
            println "OK"
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, however if I put a breakpoint on the `if` in IntelliJ IDEA I can't access the value of `param`:

- The variables view shows `this` and if I expand it I see `param`.
- If I do *Run > Evaluate Expression...* and type `this` I can see the same thing.
- BUT if I type `this.param` in the expression window:

> Cannot get the value of write-only property 'param' on MyTask.

**How can I work around resolving `param` to be the private instance variable and not the "automagic Groovy property"? Is there another magic variable for `this`?**

Modifying the code and adding `getParam()` is not an option!

## Tries

Based on the suggestion `this.@param`:

> No such field: param for class: MyTask_Decorated

I also tried `this.class.superclass.getDeclaredField("param").get(this)`:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class java_lang_reflect_Field$get can not access a member of class MyTask with modifiers "private"

Comment: `this.@param` should work

Comment: @cfrick see update, other ideas? It seems like the problem is caused by the `_Decorated` thingy.

Comment: and there is absoluetly nothing in the `Variables` window, that would lead you to the actual value?

Comment: There is `this`, I see it in the tree, but I want to call methods on it or pass it to other methods in _Evaluate Expression_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automagic Groovy property involved here. I'm not aware of a way in Groovy to access a private variable declared in a superclass (Gradle will subclass `MyTask` at runtime), and it sounds as if the debugger's expression evaluation had the same limitation.

Comment: Yep, it's the same what I concluded, so it's more like an IDEA Groovy bug, since pirating private in debugger works in Java as far as I remember.

Comment: As you see I tried reflection as well which doesn't work (the same as Java), except with `setAccessible(true)` (like Java); so debugger should have a way of playing around.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bug, but perhaps file a feature request. As you came to the same conclusion, please accept my answer.